# How to increase the intensity of a shake effect while time is passing

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm working on the animation of a square that should increase its shake while the time is passing starting from no shake till a big shake right now I have this code but it is not working properly.

```css
#BplusBT{
    position: relative;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    background-color: blue;
}
.ballepacioH{
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
    width: 4px;
    height: 4px;
    list-style-type: none;
}
```

```
<div class='column'>
    <li id='BplusBT'></li>
    <li class='ballepacioH'></li>
    <li id='BplusBT'></li>
    <li class='ballepacioH'></li>
    <li id='BplusBT'></li>
</div>
```

```
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.innerHTML = htmlLeyenda;
sym.$("recuadro_esferas").append(div);

var circles = document.querySelectorAll("#BplusBT");

for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    var circle = circles[i];

    circles.keyframes = [{
        transform: "translate(" + "0px, 2px)"
    }, {
        transform: "translate(" + "0px, -2px)"
    },{
       transform: "translate(" + "0px, 0px)"
    }];

    circle.animProps = {
        duration: 10 + 5 * i,
        easing: "ease-out",
        iterations: Infinity
    }

    var animationPlayer = circle.animate(circle.keyframes, circle.animProps);
}
```

Comment: What I'm trying to do is that he animation begins with the square completely still and then it starts shaking very slowly and increasing the velocity more and more until it shakes very fast

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's pretty simple actually, just define multiple `animation` *states* and play around with their `%`'s, then split them into groups with the same `%` difference between the *starting* and *ending* *state*. The example below has three groups with `5%`, `3%` and `1%` difference between the *states*, meaning `5%` *transforms* will take the longest and `1%` the shortest amount of the *animation duration*:

```css
.ballepacioH {
  position: relative;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: blue;
  list-style: none;
  animation: shake 2s infinite;
}

@keyframes shake {
  0%, 49% {transform: initial} /* 2s * 0.49 = 0.98s of idle time */
  /* 5% apart / starts slow */
  49.01%, 54% {transform: translate(2px, 2px)}
  59.01%, 64% {transform: translate(-2px, -2px)}
  69.01%, 74% {transform: translate(2px, 2px)}
  79.01%, 84% {transform: translate(-2px, -2px)}
  /* 3% apart */
  84.01%, 87% {transform: translate(2px, 2px)}
  87.01%, 90% {transform: translate(-2px, -2px)}
  90.01%, 93% {transform: translate(2px, 2px)}
  93.01%, 96% {transform: translate(-2px, -2px)}
  /* 1% apart / ends fast */
  96.01%, 97% {transform: translate(2px, 2px)}
  97.01%, 98% {transform: translate(-2px, -2px)}
  98.01%, 99% {transform: translate(2px, 2px)}
  99.01%, 100% {transform: translate(-2px, -2px)}
}
```

```html
<div class='column'>
  <li class='ballepacioH'></li>
</div>
```

Note: *Id's are meant to be unique, i.e. don't use the same id for multiple elements.*

Comment: Thanks! this is what I was looking for!